# Text-overflow: ellipsis not working with certain fonts?

Tags: css

Is this a well-known issue that `text-overflow: ellipsis` seems not to work with some fonts? Please check the below example. First `span` should be also ended with ellipsis and is not.
What should I do to make it work?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&subset=latin,latin-ext);

*{
  font-family: Catamaran;
}

span.eli{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.arial{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="eli">Some real long text some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text </span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span>
<span class="eli arial">Some real long text some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text </span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text overflow ellipsis not showing with some custom font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587045/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-showing-with-some-custom-font)

Answer (score 1):

You needed to include the @font-face styling for catamaran from the google webfonts helper site. This smooths over support for different browsers.

[Google Webfonts Helper Site](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/catamaran?subsets=latin)

```css
/* catamaran-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Catamaran';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Catamaran'), local('Catamaran-Regular'),
       url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/catamaran-v2-latin-regular.svg#Catamaran') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&subset=latin,latin-ext);

*{
  font-family: Catamaran;
}

span.eli{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span.arial{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span class="eli">Some real long text some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text </span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span>
<span class="eli arial">Some real long text some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text  some real long text </span><span>Short</span><span>Short</span>
```

This seems to work correctly now.

Hope it Helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Leo, but it does not look like solving the problem. The @font-face styling is only the alternative way to mport the font face. I can't see any difference in ellipsis issue.