# CSS ellipsis not working on specific web fonts

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I'm having a weird problem with a section of my site.
on an h2 tag, I want to use the CSS ellipsis property
whenever the text is overflowing the screen size.

Now, this is a repetitive section I am using on this page - and the only difference is the font applied to the h2 tag - so I know the CSS style I am using is good
(overflow: hidden, text-overflow: ellipsis, and etc...)

Can anyone help me find what is the problem?

[here is a screenshot of the section that is working the right way:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyk01.png)

[here is a screenshot of the section that is **not working** the right way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwTxF.png)

You can visit the site at -
https://www.hacollective.com/
and test in mobile size in order to see the difference.

The id of the part with the h2 problem is "col-221542828"

Thanks in advance,

Shahar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with missing ellipse points lies in the font specified for this `h2` -     `font-family: tzur,sans-serif!important`.

Here:

```
.font-tzur {
    font-family: tzur,sans-serif!important;
}
```

Which are loaded from the `font-load-tzur.css` file.

Check the correctness of loading this font `tzur`.

For example - If you put a different font, the ellipse points will appear.

Comment: Hi, Sergey,
can you speculate what in the "tzur" font can cause it?
after all, it's normal font.

Comment: Hi. Have you used this font before? On the Internet, I did not find a specification for this font. I suppose the ellipse is disabled in the font css file, or the parameter for displaying ellipses is not registered.

Comment: You can try to solve the problem with the pseudo-class `:before`. As in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28587045/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-showing-with-some-custom-font. And here's another question that is similar to your problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882188/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working-with-certain-fonts.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is in the font! If we select the `h2` tag, then on the left we will see an empty area (red square in the screenshot) - https://ibb.co/ZLsk0w7. This means that technically the points of the ellipse are present, but visually they are not !

Comment: Hi, It was indeed a problem with the font.
I have replaced the font file it's fine now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I was glad to help you!